# Run CSS animation on load and on Hover with two different iterations

Tags: html, css

I have an animation that runs on load in 3 iterations and I want to introduce a new rule that enables the same animation to only run in only 1 iteration every time my button is hovered. Everything I have tried results in either the hover animation not working at all or both animation playing on hover.

```css
@keyframes a-wobble {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  85% {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
  95% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes a-wobble {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  85% {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
  95% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes a-wobble {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  85% {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
  95% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@keyframes a-wobble2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  85% {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
  95% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes a-wobble2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  85% {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
  95% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes a-wobble2 {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  85% {
    transform: rotate(15deg);
  }
  95% {
    transform: rotate(-15deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}

#a-button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3rem;
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  cursor: pointer;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.a-icon {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: a-wobble 1.5s 3;
  animation: a-wobble 1.5s 3;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.a-button {
  all: unset;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid #E10000 1px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  background: #E10000;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

.a-icon-size {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}


/*I want this to only run this animation, not both*/

.a-button:hover>.a-icon {
  animation: a-wobble2 1.5s 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="a-button bottom"><h3>Test </h3><div id="a-icon" class="a-icon a-icon-size"></div></button>

</div>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @rx2347 that's perfect, thank you! Not sure how I didn't come across this solution, been searching for some time.

Comment: I typed "prevent css animation from rerunning" into the search bar up top ;)